# Karma - SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "NOT"

Tags: json, karma-mocha

When executing karma test, we are intermittently getting the below error:

```
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 15 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.46 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 15 SUCCESS (2.006 secs / 0.46 secs)
[32mFinished in 2.006 secs / 0.46 secs[39m
[4m[1mSUMMARY:[22m[24m    
[32m[32m✔[32m 15 tests completed[39m PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR  

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "NOT" at   test/unit/test.entry.js:65665
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "NOT"at /test/unit/test.entry.js:65665
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 15 ERROR (2.006 secs / 0.46 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 15 ERROR (2.07 secs / 0.46 secs)

[31m✖[39m[31m Error while running the tests! Exit code: 1[39m

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

We are using:
karma --> "0.13.22"

The test seems to pass(Executed 15 of 15 SUCCESS), but later it fails because of JSON parse error (Executed 15 of 15 ERROR), and not sure where that is coming from.

Is there a way to supress this error to stop failing the build in the jenkins or any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is related to a "NOT FOUND" with status code 404, while your test is expecting to recieve a JSON value. I just had a similar issue, where my mocks were ignored, so the api url was called.
Tests were passing but because the call was returning a 404, while my function was expecting a json, this error occured.
Although some time has passed, this may help somebody who is experiencing the same issue.